# Getting total disk space used and remaining disk space?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, jclouds

I'm using `Apache Jclouds` to get `AWS EC2 CPU` usage metrics. But I do not see any methods to get the total disk space and the remaining disk space. Is there any other API `which provides disk usage information`?

Answer (score 1):

By default, EC2 reports to CloudWatch only hypervisor visible metrics, such as CPU and I/O. You can use the "[Monitoring Scripts for Amazon EC2 Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/mon-scripts.html)" to send memory, swap and disk usage as custom metrics to CloudWatch.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that this is not, in any sense, a "limitation" in EC2 or EBS -- these metrics have to be actively pushed to Cloudwatch by code you install and run on your instance.   AWS *can't* autonomously report on metrics like disk or memory usage, because to do so would require AWS to have a level of access to your instance's internals that would be entirely inappropriate for a cloud infrastructure provider to have. This is very different from CPU or overall I/O utilization, which is known to the hypervisor, of necessity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not want AWS to push metrics to any on-premise application. Is there any API to get the Disk usage so that on-premise application can call the API?

Comment: Yes, you can get the metric statistics using either the CLI [ http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-statistics.html ] or AWS SDKs [ e.g. java: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/AmazonCloudWatchClient.html#getMetricStatistics(com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.model.GetMetricStatisticsRequest) ]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Alarm and Metric](http://jclouds.apache.org/reference/javadoc/1.9.x/org/jclouds/cloudwatch/features/package-summary.html) APIs to talk to CloudWatch. You'll have to create a context using the "cloudwatch" api id.

Comment: These APIs gives CPU utilization metrics but not Disk usage metrics.